# Cocoapods Errors when using Jetbrains AppCode

Tags: swift, cocoapods, jetbrains-ide, appcode

I just switched over from Xcode 8 to JetBrain AppCode 2016.3 due to Xcode's terribly slow performance.  When on Xcode, I could build our app (via Workspace for Cocoapods) without any errors.  After opening the Workspace in AppCode, I tried to debug the code and received 5,920 errors.  All of the errors are coming from various Pods (Alamofire, ActiveLabel, Kingfisher, etc).

I've updated each of the Pods; successfully built the app on Xcode; but it will not work on AppCode.

Here are some of the errors I'm receiving:
ActiveBuilder.swift (ActiveLable)
Error:(37,48) boolean condition requires 'where' to separate it from variable binding
Error:(35,41) use of unresolved identifier 'CharacterSet'
Error:(85,24) value of type 'NSString' has no member 'substring'
...

I would greatly appreciate any help in solving this, as I really want to get away from Xcode and start using AppCode.  Thank you.

Comment: AppCode doesn't really support Swift 3 yet: https://blog.jetbrains.com/objc/2016/12/appcode-2016-3-release/#more-5305

Comment: Oh no!!!!  Thanks for sharing, I imagine that is the cause for the errors.  It's unfortunate, as AppCode has a lot of great features and I found autocomplete to be faster than Xcode 8.

Answer (score 0):

As this issue is related to building the project and AppCode just invokes xcodebuild to build the project, it is not related to Swift 3 support. As for me it looks more like the **.xcodeproj** is opened in AppCode instead of **.xcworkspace**. Could you please share the build log (see the screenshot attached) in our [tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/OC) and mention the link to ticket here?

[image: build log]